# Is it possible to change a pom file after uploading it to Maven Central?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-central

Is it possible to change a pom file of a jar after uploading it to Maven Central?

E.g., if I've uploaded a jar with a set of dependencies, and after the upload found out one of the dependencies was wrong - can I change the pom and upload it, and still have the same version number?

My logic says the answer is no, but my boss insists the answer is yes, and this issue affects his decision not to rely on Maven central repository in our project's build.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If it is uploaded into staging repository you can't change the pom itself but you can drop the staging repository and try again. Furthermore

Comment: Why are you relying on Maven Central?

Comment: @khmarbaise currently we store our 3rd party dependencies in our SVN. I would like to use a more modern approach of gradle+artifactory, where artifactory downloads new dependecies from maven-central

Comment: Than configure Artifactory appropriately and this works also with Maven. No relationship to Gradle. Storing into SVN does not make sense. Neither with Maven nor with Gradle.